# Replicate SAS weighted frequencies and chisq-test in R

Tags: r, weighted

I'm trying to replicate a SAS frequency count, and chisq-test, in R.

The sas data and code:

```
DATA test; 
   INPUT sex $ group weight ; 
   DATALINES; 
F  1  0.8 
M  1  0.9
F  1  1.0
M  1  1.1
F  1  1.2
M  1  1.3
F  2  1.4
M  2  1.5
F  2  1.6
M  2  1.7
F  1  0.8 
M  1  0.9
F  1  1.0
M  1  1.1
F  1  1.2
M  1  1.3
F  2  1.4
M  2  1.5
F  2  1.6
M  2  1.7
F  1  0.8 
M  1  0.9
F  1  1.0
M  1  1.1
F  1  1.2
M  1  1.3
F  2  1.4
M  2  1.5
F  2  1.6
M  2  1.7
;


/* result1 (unweighted) */
proc freq data=test;
tables sex * group / chisq ;
run;


/* result2 (weighted) */
proc freq data=test;
tables sex * group / chisq ;
weight weight;
run;
```

**SAS-result1 (unweighted) below can be replicated in R**

[image]

```
test <-  structure(list(sex = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), 
    group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L), weight = c(0.8, 0.9, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 
    1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 
    1.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7)), .Names = c("sex", 
"group", "weight"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L
)) 


table( test$sex, test$group)
chisq.test( table( test$sex, test$group) )
```

In R:

[image]

**SAS-result2, I dont know how to do in R:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(weights)
wtd.chi.sq(test$sex, test$group, weight = test$weight)
#      Chisq          df     p.value 
#0.002215526 1.000000000 0.962457933
```